# Retrieve value of a single radio button

Tags: radio-button

I am trying to pull the value of the checked radio button from a form element using javascript. The number of radio buttons in the form is not fixed as it is dynamically retrieved when a page reloads.
**Issue:** When there is more than one radio button in the form, I am able to fetch the value of the checked radio using the loop:

```
for (var i=0; i < document.form2.buddy_list.length; i++)
{
if (document.form2.buddy_list[i].checked)
{
selected_buddy_intn = document.form2.buddy_list[i].value;
}
}
```

But, the scenario when there is only one radio button inside the form, In that case, the above technique doesn't work. Any suggestions appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that loop condition is not satisfied and that's why no iteration is made. Try this line instead of your first line:`for (var i=0; i <= document.form2.buddy_list.length; i++)`. And you can use Mozilla FireBug or Opera Dragonfly to debug javascripts and see what's wrong

Comment: I tried to display the length of the radio button array using the following code: alert(document.form2.buddy_list.length);   But this is giving the output : 'Undefined'.

Comment: Could you put your HTML file with script to pastebin or any other code exchange service?